# pulling data from firebase and displaying on page

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have checked the documentation on angularfire for retrieving and displaying data and am having trouble with it! I think I am returning the data but am just not displaying it. here is a link to my plnker: http://plnkr.co/edit/LZ24sRoSJjuCHQnEGzQz?p=preview

Index

```
      <h1 ng-repeat="group in data.groups">{{group.name}}</h1>
```

JS

```
      $scope.newGroup = {
        name: '',
        status: ''
      };

      $scope.addGroup = function(newGroup) {

        groupsService.addGroup(newGroup);

        $scope.newGroup = {
            name: '',
            status: ''
        };

      };

    .factory('groupsService', ['$firebase', 'FIREBASE_URI',
      function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URI) {
        var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URI);

        var groups = $firebase(ref).$asArray();

        var getGroups = function(){
          return groups;
        };

        var addGroup = function (newGroup) {
          console.log(newGroup)
          groups.$add(newGroup);
        };

        return {
          getGroups: getGroups,
          addGroup: addGroup,

        }
```

Comment: the part displaying groups is missing. is your $scope.data.groups empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view in the plunkr doesn't contain the ng-repeat markup. But if I add these fragments, it works as expected.

In the controller you need to add the array to the scope:

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.groups = groupsService.getGroups();
```

Then in the view, you loop over the groups inside the element that binds the controller:

```
<form ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h1 ng-repeat="group in data.groups">{{group.name}}</h1>
</form>
```

Output

> hi
>
> hi
>
> dfgdfg

Updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/HWZj5szozMMBXGadu2U6?p=preview